# htaccess block access to directory but allow access to files

Tags: htaccess, looking-for-a-script, 403-forbidden

I need to block directory access but allow access to files if typed into a browser.

Also would like this to load my custom 403.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/403.shtml
```

Both lines go into an .htaccess file in your root directory

Comment: Thanks but sorry this does not allow access to files.

Comment: Do you have any error? Code snippet above must work, if AllowOverride in server's config allow you to use redefines in htaccess

Comment: This does block directory access, however it also blocks file access.  Typing either into a browser gives the 403.

I'm a bit new to this stuff so I'm not certain on AllowOverride.

Comment: I must admit I'm a bit surprised no one has an answer for this.

Comment: My answer is correct. If it doesn't work for you then your server is not correctly configured or not configured to allow you to do this.

Comment: My mistake, thank you John.  It was hot-linking which was enabled causing my confusion.